# layout_weight overlapping the views

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am having trouble with assigning the `layout_weight` to the views since it keeps overlapping with one another. I have set the `weightSum = 5` and the `layout_weight` of each view as `0.1, 0.15, 2, 2.5, 0.125, 0.125` which in total adds up to **5** but I still can't figure out why it is overlapping.

This is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <View
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@color/grey_400" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/white" />

    <View
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/grey_400"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="183dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="61dp"
            android:text="Report"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_400" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_date_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_time_id"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Time"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="MR Number:"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_mr_number_id"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:text="P-142356"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Age:"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_age_id"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="71"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Eye:"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_eye_id"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="RIGHT"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test type:"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Supra threshold 24-2"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Fixation Monitor:"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:id="@+id/textView" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="BLIND SPOT"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.5"
        app:cardElevation="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Fixation Loss:"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_fixation_loss_id"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0 / 10"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="False Positive:"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_falsePositive_points_id"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0 / 10"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="False Negative:"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_falseNegative_points_id"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0 / 54"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Test Duration:"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_test_duration_id"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="N/A"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Place:"
                    android:textSize="17dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_place_id"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="N/A"
                    android:textAllCaps="true"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.125"
        android:text="NEW TEST"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.125"
        android:text="NEW TEST"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The result I am getting is something like this,
[image]

But want I actually want is something like this,
[image]

Comment: You are using too much weight, it means too much work and less performance when inflating and measuring the layout. You may consider using ConstraintLayout instead of this complex layout.

Comment: Thank you so much, the app was getting laggy and I couldn't figure out why, this might be one of the reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manage weight according to minimum requirement of size. I have set `android:weightSum="7"` and then distribute in `0.5, 0.5, 2.5, 2.5, 0.5, 0.5` according to text size or minimum requirement according to view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <View
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4dp"
            android:background="@color/grey_400" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="320dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/white" />

        <View
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_width="4dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/grey_400"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="7">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:text="Report"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="4dp"
                android:background="@color/grey_400" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_date_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Date"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_time_id"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="Time"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="MR Number:"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_mr_number_id"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:text="P-142356"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Age:"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_age_id"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="71"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Eye:"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_eye_id"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="RIGHT"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Test type:"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Supra threshold 24-2"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Fixation Monitor:"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:id="@+id/textView" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="BLIND SPOT"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.5"
            app:cardElevation="10dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Fixation Loss:"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_fixation_loss_id"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0 / 10"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="False Positive:"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_falsePositive_points_id"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0 / 10"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="False Negative:"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_falseNegative_points_id"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="0 / 54"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Test Duration:"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_test_duration_id"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="N/A"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Place:"
                        android:textSize="17dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/black" />

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_weight="1" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_place_id"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="N/A"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textSize="15dp"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey_500"/>


                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="NEW TEST"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:text="NEW TEST"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves the problem. Also, with `weightSum` as `5`, I just found out that I was assigning too less weight for the first two `layout_weight` so I changed them to `0.5` and `0.6` and adjusted the rest of the weight accordingly.

Comment: Yes, the weight was too much less. so I said that use weight according to view. I set weight according to number of lines 0.5 weight per line view.